# My form validate function will not run.

Tags: organic-groups, forms

I am using Organic Groups. That module has a form where you add new members to a group. I would like to run additional validation on that form. I use hook_form_alter and can identify the form. I add a validate callback and verify its been added to the form array. Yet that function never runs. I don't know why.

```
function organization_control_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'og_ui_add_users'){
    dpm("Validation Added");
    //This dpm displays. 

    $form["#validate"][] = 'organization_control_og_size_control_form_validate';
    //I have also tried running my validate function first, like this
      //array_unshift($form["#validate"],'organization_control_og_size_control_form_validate');
    //I have also tried only running my validation, like this
      //$form["#validate"] = array('organization_control_og_size_control_form_validate');

    dpm("form");  
    dpm($form);
    //This dpm shows the validate callback has been added. 
  }
}

function organization_control_og_size_control_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
  dpm("Validation Started");
  //This dpm NEVER shows

  //hard code an error for testing
  $subscriptionInfo['field_total_seats_value'] = 4;

  dpm("Validation Run 2");
  //This dpm NEVER shows

  if($organzational_control_organization_size >=  $subscriptionInfo['field_total_seats_value']){
    dpm("ERROR");
    //This dpm NEVER shows

    form_set_error('edit-name', t('Your Organization has reached is current license size limit.'));
    //This error is not displayed and the form submissions continues and succeeds. 
  }
  else{
    dpm("It thinks its Okay");
    //This dpm NEVER shows
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you're not using a reference to `$form`.

Change your function declaration to:

`function organization_control_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){`

Note the `&` in front of $form.  This means you're actually working on the variable as passed to the function, not a copy, or at least that's my understanding of it.

A useful thing to do to avoid this kind of error with hooks is to check out the [API for the hook you are trying to use](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and copy the parameters verbatim.